# Proposition 2.2.12 Analysis I Tao

Tags: real-analysis

$(f)$ $a<b$ $if$ $and$ $only$ $if$ $b=a+d$ $for$ $some$ $positive$ $number$ $d$

In my book $a<b$ is defined as $a\leq b$ $and$ $a\neq b$
and $a\leq b$ is by def. $b=a+d$ $for$ $some$ $natural$ $number$ $d$

By using this and Peano axioms, how do I prove (f)?

Comment: For which set of number do you want to prove the statement? The natural numbers?

Comment: Yes, the natural numbers

Comment: And the natrural numbers are $0,1,2,3,\dots$?

Comment: Yes they are defined like that

Answer (score 3):

Let $\mathbb{N}$ denote the set of natural numbers and $a, b \in \mathbb{N}$.

1) Let $a < b$. Then $b = a  + d$ for some $d \in \mathbb{N}$ and $a \ne b$. Hence $d = 0$ is impossible because $a + 0 = a$, that is,  $b = a  + d$ for some positive $d \in \mathbb{N}$.

2) Let $b = a  + d$ for some positive $d \in \mathbb{N}$. Then certainly $a \le b$. But $a = b$ is impossible because in that case $a = a + d$ which implies $d = 0$.

In the last step I have assumed that the "usual properties" of $+$ have already been proved.